# Why does the translate animation not work?

Tags: android, animation

I have an activity and its contentView layout is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/schedule_item_list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/item_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone" >
<!-- some buttons  -->
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to show and hide the bottom linearlayout so to make it act like a bottom menu, I create a function like this:

```
 private void showBottomMenuView()
{
    if (mBottomMenuView.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
        Animation slideinAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        slideinAnimation.setDuration(300);
        mBottomMenuView.startAnimation(slideinAnimation);
        mBottomMenuView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

however it doesn't work when I want to show the bottom layout(mBottomMenuView). the view won't slide in from bottom smoothly, it just appear suddenly

But when i load a animation from xml, it did work .

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:fromYDelta="100%"
    android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="300"/>
</set>


private void showBottomMenuView()
{
    if (mBottomMenuView.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
        Animation slideinAnimation =  AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.slide_in);
        mBottomMenuView.startAnimation(slideinAnimation);
        mBottomMenuView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

why the previous new animation didn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your want to measure your screen height then use

```
Animation slideinAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, mesureHeight, 0.0f);
```

or

```
Animation slideinAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,0.0f,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1.0f,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I looked up the source and found the four-parameters TranslateAnimation constructor set the from and to type as ABSLOUTE default